# How to debug Kubernetes on the proper way?

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to run Istio to play around, but I facing issues with my local kubernetes installation and I am successfuly stack with a way of debug my installation

That is a my current situation:

```
root@node1:/tmp/istio-0.1.5# kubectl get svc
NAME            CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                       AGE
grafana         10.233.2.70     <pending>     3000:31202/TCP                1h
istio-egress    10.233.39.101   <none>        80/TCP                        1h
istio-ingress   10.233.48.51    <pending>     80:30982/TCP,443:31195/TCP    1h
istio-manager   10.233.2.109    <none>        8080/TCP,8081/TCP             1h
istio-mixer     10.233.39.58    <none>        9091/TCP,9094/TCP,42422/TCP   1h
kubernetes      10.233.0.1      <none>        443/TCP                       4h
prometheus      10.233.63.20    <pending>     9090:32170/TCP                1h
servicegraph    10.233.39.104   <pending>     8088:30814/TCP                1h

root@node1:/tmp/istio-0.1.5# kubectl get pods
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
grafana-1261931457-3hx2p         0/1       Pending   0          1h
istio-ca-3887035158-6p3b0        0/1       Pending   0          1h
istio-egress-1920226302-vmlx1    0/1       Pending   0          1h
istio-ingress-2112208289-ctxj5   0/1       Pending   0          1h
istio-manager-2910860705-z28dp   0/2       Pending   0          1h
istio-mixer-2335471611-rsrhb     0/1       Pending   0          1h
prometheus-3067433533-l2m48      0/1       Pending   0          1h
servicegraph-3127588006-1k5rg    0/1       Pending   0          1h

 kubectl get rs
NAME                       DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
grafana-1261931457         1         1         0         1h
istio-ca-3887035158        1         1         0         1h
istio-egress-1920226302    1         1         0         1h
istio-ingress-2112208289   1         1         0         1h
istio-manager-2910860705   1         1         0         1h
istio-mixer-2335471611     1         1         0         1h
prometheus-3067433533      1         1         0         1h
servicegraph-3127588006    1         1         0         1h

kubectl get pods --show-labels
NAME                             READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       LABELS
grafana-1261931457-3hx2p         0/1       Pending   0          1h        app=grafana,pod-template-hash=1261931457
istio-ca-3887035158-6p3b0        0/1       Pending   0          1h        istio=istio-ca,pod-template-hash=3887035158
istio-egress-1920226302-vmlx1    0/1       Pending   0          1h        istio=egress,pod-template-hash=1920226302
istio-ingress-2112208289-ctxj5   0/1       Pending   0          1h        istio=ingress,pod-template-hash=2112208289
istio-manager-2910860705-z28dp   0/2       Pending   0          1h        istio=manager,pod-template-hash=2910860705
istio-mixer-2335471611-rsrhb     0/1       Pending   0          1h        istio=mixer,pod-template-hash=2335471611
prometheus-3067433533-l2m48      0/1       Pending   0          1h        app=prometheus,pod-template-hash=3067433533
servicegraph-3127588006-1k5rg    0/1       Pending   0          1h        app=servicegraph,pod-template-hash=3127588006

root@node1:/tmp/istio-0.1.5# kubectl get nodes --show-labels
NAME      STATUS    AGE       VERSION           LABELS
node1     Ready     5h        v1.6.4+coreos.0   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/hostname=node1,node-role.kubernetes.io/master=true,node-role.kubernetes.io/node=true
node2     Ready     5h        v1.6.4+coreos.0   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/hostname=node2,node-role.kubernetes.io/master=true,node-role.kubernetes.io/node=true
node3     Ready     5h        v1.6.4+coreos.0   app=prometeus,beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/hostname=node3,node-role.kubernetes.io/node=true
node4     Ready     5h        v1.6.4+coreos.0   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/hostname=node4,node-role.kubernetes.io/node=true
```

Unfortunately, after I read out most of documentation, I found out only few way to debug an installation

```
journalctl -r -u kubelet
kubectl get events
kubectl describe deployment
```

Is there any common workflow to debug Kubernetes installation?

Comment: Thats a complicated question.  how are you building your cluster? kubeadm? kops? something else?  Please add to your original post.   Also, post the info from your kube-system ns as well.

Comment: Thank you for the guess, looks like problem related to namespaces:

root@node1:~# kubectl get namespaces
NAME          STATUS    AGE
default       Active    21h
kube-public   Active    21h
kube-system   Active    21h

Answer (score 0):

Its in the documentation. follow the POD troubleshooting steps

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-application/

Comment: Actually, this is a good starting point, but not cover my case. F.e all my pods in the state pending and there is not to much explanation. Even events log is clear, deploy status is ok, describe is not showing anything criminal

Comment: looks the pod details 'kubectl describe pod grafana-1261931457-3hx2p ' also see this pod any logs 'kubectl logs grafana-1261931457-3hx2p '

Comment: Can you give some more details about your cluster environment? are you running in VM?

Comment: yes, I running on 4 vm's with internal network between them

Comment: `cloud-user@node3:~$ kubectl get nodes
NAME      STATUS    AGE       VERSION`
`node1     Ready     26m       v1.6.4+coreos.0`
`node2     Ready     26m       v1.6.4+coreos.0`
`node3     Ready     26m       v1.6.4+coreos.0`
`node4     Ready     26m       v1.6.4+coreos.0`
`cloud-user@node3:~$ kubectl get svc`
`NAME         CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE`
`kubernetes   10.233.0.1   <none>        443/TCP   27m`